# How to I add a counter to this while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, counter

I need to add a counter to my while loop, so that I can know how many times the loop iterated.

```
var popSize = 100;
var endSize = 200;

var x = popSize / 3;     
var y = popSize / 4;     

while (popSize < endSize) 
{
    popSize = popSize + x - y; 
    popSize++;        
}
console.log(popSize);
```

Comment: By adding another variable, for example, `counter`, to the variable declarations, initialized to zero, and increment it inside the loop. Your current loop appears to use `popSize` for (at least) two different purposes. Adding a new variable is no different than how you've already used several.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var counter = 0;

while (popSize < endSize) 
{
    popSize = popSize + x - y; 
    popSize++;        
    counter++;
}

console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the iterations in a variable and increment it inside the loop:

```js
var popSize = 100;
var endSize = 200;

var iterations = 0
var x = popSize / 3;
var y = popSize / 4;

while (popSize < endSize) {
  iterations++;
  popSize = popSize + x - y;
  popSize++;
}
console.log(popSize);
console.log('iterations', iterations)
```